# assign an id to a button generated by loop

Tags: angular

I want to assign an id to button & to the li that it belongs in order to know **which button of which li** of has been clicked

```
 <ul class="list-group">  
       <li class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let post of posts; let i = index"  > 

                        <p > {{  post.title }} </p>

             <button class="btn btn-success" (click)="onOk()" > ok</button> 

              </li>
        </ul>
```

Comment: Pass `i` into the function you're calling on click: `(click)="onOk(i)"`

Comment: What do you need it for? for styling purpose? or for logic to know which li was clicked?

Comment: @R.Richards and then how can I make the comparaison between the i of the buton and the i of the li ?

Comment: If passing the index (`i`) doesn't work for that, does the `post` have an id you could pass instead? Does the posted answer get you where you need to be?

Comment: @R.Richards the i is the id of the iteration namely the post !

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML Template

```
<ul class="list-group">  
   <li class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let post of posts; let i = index" [class.highlight]="post.clicked"> 
      <p > {{  post.title }} </p>
      <button class="btn btn-success" (click)="onOk(i)">ok</button> 
   </li>
</ul>
```

Your component TS

```
onOk(index: number) {
   const post = this.posts[index];
   post.clicked = true; // you may toggle it
}
```

Your CSS/SCSS

```
   .highlight {
      background-color: blue;
   }
```

**Make sure your POST interface has a `clicked` declared and POSTS have clicked initialized to false to begin with.**

Comment: after assigning id to it I have to compare if li.id == button.id how to write it ?

Comment: can you tell me what are you trying to achieve (li.id===button.id does not make sense to me)?

Comment: I want to compare whether the id of the button is equal to the id of the li

Comment: why do you need to compare the ids?

Comment: if they are equal a color should be displayed

Comment: so you want to highlight the li when the corresponding button is pressed?

Comment: Property 'clicked' does not exist on type

Comment: plus I prefer compare ids in the template not in the ts

Comment: did you declare `clicked` in your Post interface?

Answer (score 0):

You can add `id` to your `li` element or the button and use it to style the same or, just use the `$event` object to find the parent `li` for button and make the styles changes.

Here is a [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4dhued) for your situation.

```
 <ul class="list-group">  
       <li class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let post of posts; let i = index"  id="post-{{i}}"> 

                        <p > {{  post.title }} </p>

             <button class="btn btn-success" (click)="onOk($event)" id="btnPost{{i}}"> ok</button> 

              </li>
        </ul>
```

Now you have in your component, change the style of clicked `li` button:

```
onOk($event: Event) {
    $event.srcElement.parentElement.style.backgroundColor = 'Green';
    $event.srcElement.parentElement.style.color = 'Yellow';
}
```

**EDIT**:----- UPDATED the stackblitz example too

You can also use the modals on list to set styles from HTML using `ngStyle`:

```
<ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let post of posts; let i = index" id="post-{{i}}" 
     [ngStyle]="{'background-color':clicked[i] ? 'green' : 'red' }">

        <p> {{ post.title }} </p>

        <button class="btn btn-success" (click)="clicked[i] = true" > ok</button> 

              </li>
        </ul>
```

In The component just have : `clicked = [];`

Comment: it seems like jquery isn't it ? in fact I prefer to do the comparaison in the html file not in the ts... could u help me to acheive it !

Comment: @alex, upadted answer to use HTML only and set `ngStyle` using modals. Updated stackblitz too

Comment: aa alright, the writing seemed to me so... I'm new to angular programming. so it is not possible to comare the li id & the button's id in the template ?

Comment: assuming it's all dynamic, you can have a comparison but not be able to trigger it on click inside HTML, it has to go to `ts`

Comment: I didn't understand this    id="post-{{i}}"

Comment: This just creates `id="post-1"` and changes to `post-2` and so on based on index of `*ngFor` and different objects in `posts` array. You can also use `id="{{post.id}}"` as well if your `post` object has an id in it.

Comment: (click)="clicked[i] and clicked refers to what ?

Comment: `clicked` is the array defined in component, It's your `ngModel` binding to selected li. and defined in component. Please see the answer (last line)

Comment: Can you please accept the answer if it helped you or upvote? Thanks